# Full width content when no sidebar using Twitter BootStrap Css Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the twitter bootstrap css toolkit for building master page for an application in asp.net webforms 2.0( also .NET 2.0). Nothing of a programming question though it is about design i got page with

```
    Header
    Breadcrumb
    Maincontent
    -leftsidebar
    -pageContent
    -rightsidebar
    Footer
```

yeah this is one of those sidebar questions, i got the HTML like below

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <!--Place holder for left sidebar-->
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="phLeftSidebar">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <!--Place holder for main content-->
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="phPageContent">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <!--Place holder for right sidebar-->
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="phRightSidebar">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
```

#### Question

In one of the content(child) pages i got no content for the left sidebar & i was expecting the middle content to take that space too since the right sidebar was spanning only 4 grids. So how do i make the `content section` take up the available space on absence of either `right or left sidebar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a question much similar to this, you can take a look at the result [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8947920/680398).

What it basically came down to was creating a new set of classes that you can add to your `.content` area in your child page so it can conform to your sidebars.

Just add this to your main CSS and add a class to your `.content` area according to your sidebar needs:

```
.fixed-fluid {
    margin-left: 240px;
}
.fluid-fixed {
    margin-right: 240px;
    margin-left:auto !important;
}
.fixed-fixed {
    margin: 0 240px;
}
```

Here is a demo of how it looks:

- Without left sidebar: http://jsfiddle.net/6vPqA/4/show/
- Without right sidebar: http://jsfiddle.net/6vPqA/5/show/