# Bootstrap: Fixed gutter width in fluid layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have different layouts like [left|content|right] and [left|content] or [content|right] when using the fluid layout the gutter between the "cells" is also fluid and has a percentage value. But I would like to have a fixed width for the gutter like 10px or 20px between the left/right and content areas.

Any suggestion how to make this work? I've already tried it but ended always up with wildly shifting elements.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Answered a question like this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947920/how-do-i-get-a-three-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap/8949800#8949800), what it basically came down too was creating a set of classes to offset the main container depending on how many sidebars you have, like so:

**CSS**

```
.fixed-fluid {
    margin-left: 240px;
}
.fluid-fixed {
    margin-right: 240px;
    margin-left:auto !important;
}
.fixed-fixed {
    margin: 0 240px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/6vPqA/13/show/), edit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/6vPqA/13/).

Comment: The demo, how can I make the 3 columns in the main content also to have a gutter of just 20px instead being fluid? Same technique as shown above for the sidebars I guess? Going to play with it this weekend. Basically I want to understand how to have a few fluid columns but make their contents have a fixed gutter space.

Comment: @burzum im confused, you mean how do you get a fixed container? As opposed to the way it is now? The gutter there is 20px all around, if you look at the `.fixed-fixed` class margin you can see that it is set to `margin: 0 240px;`, the sidebars are both width 220px, plus an extra 20px (totalling 240px) of margin to form that gutter you see surrounding the main container.