# Bootstrap fixed size column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I need to do fixed width right column column in bootstrap, but left column will be responsive.

I use bootstrap 2.3.2

[image]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1375170941.png))</sub>

Right column will not be resized at all screen size.

Comment: How will this work? What do you mean by 'responsive' (do you mean it'll break down at 797px like normal bootstrap)?

Comment: Right column will not be resized at all screen size

Comment: why the downvote? looks like a valid programming question to me

Comment: can show what bootstrap classes u have used for container, left and right column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My basic solution below ([see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/KacFD/2)). I've padded out the CSS to demonstrate the blocks with colours, but all you really need to do is as follows:

Fixed element

- Set it to `float:right`
- Apply a fixed width to it

Fluid row element

- Apply `padding/margin-right` equal to the width of the fixed element
- Apply `box-sizing:border-box`, so that the 100% width against the `.row-fluid` element persists, but the margin/padding added doesn't push it out further. The markup below shows the minimum you'll need.

**CSS**

```
#fixed-width { 
    width:100px;
    float:right;
}
#fluid.row-fluid {
    margin-right:100px;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            box-sizing:border-box;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="fixed-width">Content...</div>
    <div id="fluid" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">a</div>
        <div class="span4">b</div>
        <div class="span4">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this kind of design it's not provided by bootstrap, but there are simple solutions.

Here is one, see the accepted answer to this previous SO question [Bootstrap: Fixed gutter width in fluid layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739268/bootstrap-fixed-gutter-width-in-fluid-layout/9739345#9739345)

and in particular, this css tricks

```
.fluid-fixed {
  margin-right: 240px;
  margin-left:auto !important;
}
```

as shown in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6vPqA/808/