# Fluid twitter bootstrap layout with min-width columns on left and right (sidebars)

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I need to create a page layout like in the following illustration with twitter bootstrap:

[image: sidebar-content-sidebar]
The left and right sidebars should have a width of at least lets say 300px. If there is more space they can grow but they should not shrink (elsewhere navigation links will get cut).
The middle column should fill the entire space left.

I have tried it by assigning a min-width to the sidebar spans, but in this case the last sidebar (b) will switch to the next line if the browser content area width gets below 1300px.
I`m not using responsive twitter bs css.

Is there a way to avoid this ? I have already found some approaches, but only without bootstrap, which do not work for me.

As the site I am talking about is already running I will not paste code here but please take a look at it live at http://kunden.tommy-computer.at/fsv_noetsch/ (german)

Thank you for your help !

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: Hate to say it, but that sounds exactly like a job for responsive bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found a very well working solution (for me) here also at StackOverflow:
[How do I get a three column layout with Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947920/how-do-i-get-a-three-column-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap?rq=1)

Anyway thank you very much for your help guys !

Answer (score 4):

If you use Bootstrap 2 responsive you can do something with fixed sidebars on the left and right.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed">
       ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      main content
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed">
       ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

example: http://bootply.com/60284

You can decrease/increase the spanX accordingly if you want sidebars narrower/wider etc..

---

**Related**
[Bootstrap 4 Holy Grail Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617595/bootstrap-4-holy-grail-layout/42624160#42624160)

Comment: Hi skelly! That`s near the behaviour like I wanted it to be but what I don`t want (in my case) is that the sidebars arrange under each other if a certain width is undercut. I tried to avoid it with a min-width for the container, but didn`t work. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are using a grid system, so you should stick with the given grids widths. (even tought 99% of my clients who wants their design to be coded with bootstrap never respect the grid system and use random width, that kills the point of using a grid system)

If you change the width for one grid you must change it for the other too or it won't fit. (a.k.a you must edit the .span8 width to fit the content).