# Bootstrap 4 sidenav on mobile is not on left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sidebar

Hello In my project I have a left sidebar with menu items. My sidenav code:

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

/* fixed and fluid only on sm and up */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .fixed {
        flex: 0 0 200px;
        min-height: 100vh;
        min-width: 180px;
    }
    .col .fluid {
       min-height: 100vh;
    }
    .flex-grow {
       flex:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <!-- left sidebar -->
        <div class="col-md-2 fixed pl-0 py-3 bg-light">
            <ul class="nav flex-md-column flex-nowrap justify-content-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-truncate" href="#">Top on mobile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- center content -->
        <div class="col fluid d-flex flex-column p-0">
            <nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#first">Bootstrap 4</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto py-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
                    ☰
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link page-scroll" data-toggle="modal" title="A free Bootstrap theme" href="#aboutModal">About</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- main content -->
            <div class="flex-grow">
                <div class="col-12 py-4">
                    <h3 class="text-primary hidden-sm-down">Fixed-Fluid-Fixed <span class="small">(Holy Grail Layout)</span></h3>
                    <h6>Change the width to see the fixed-width side columns.</h6>
                    <p>Wolf moon retro jean shorts chambray sustainable roof party. Shoreditch vegan artisan Helvetica. Tattooed Codeply Echo Park Godard kogi, next level irony ennui twee squid fap selvage. Meggings flannel Brooklyn literally small batch,
                        mumblecore PBR try-hard kale chips. Brooklyn vinyl lumbersexual bicycle rights, viral fap cronut leggings squid chillwave pickled gentrify mustache. 3 wolf moon hashtag church-key Odd Future. Austin messenger bag normcore, Helvetica
                        Williamsburg sartorial tote bag distillery Portland before they sold out gastropub taxidermy Vice.</p>
                    <p>More sustainable roof party. Shoreditch vegan artisan Helvetica. Tattooed Codeply Echo Park Godard kogi, next level irony ennui twee squid fap selvage. Meggings flannel Brooklyn literally small batch,
                        mumblecore PBR try-hard kale chips. Brooklyn vinyl lumbersexual bicycle rights, viral fap cronut leggings squid chillwave pickled gentrify mustache. 3 wolf moon hashtag church-key Odd Future. Austin messenger bag normcore, Helvetica
                        Williamsburg sartorial tote bag distillery Portland before they sold out gastropub taxidermy Vice.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                            <div class="card card-block mb-2">
                                <h2 class="text-center"><span class="label label-danger">Snippets</span></h2>
                                <h1 class="text-center">311</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-2">
                            <div class="card card-block">
                                <h2 class="text-center"><span class="label label-danger">Downloads</span></h2>
                                <h1 class="text-center">982</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-2">
                            <div class="card card-block">
                                <h2 class="text-center"><span class="label label-danger">Sales</span></h2>
                                <h1 class="text-center">112</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-2">
                            <div class="card card-block">
                                <h2 class="text-center"><span class="label label-danger">Questions</span></h2>
                                <h1 class="text-center">209</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /main content -->

            <footer class="navbar navbar-expand bg-light navbar-light">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Footer</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">More</a></li>
                </ul>
            </footer>

        </div>

        
    </div>
</div>
<div id="aboutModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine modal body…</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How I can do this sidenav on mobile on left? Now this sidebar on up on header. I need help with bootstrap 4, In this example I use `container-fluid`.  On mobile he's on up, but not left. How I can resolve this problem? Please help resolve this bug with bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug with Bootstrap 4 and it looks like the [code was copied from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617595/bootstrap-4-holy-grail-layout/42624160#42624160). Look at the columns used in markup, and **read [how the Bootstrap grid works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#stacked-to-horizontal)**. The left sidebar is `col-md-2` so it's going to stack vertically once the `md` breakpoint of `768px` is reached.

As the Bootstrap docs state...

> "*For grids that are the same from the smallest of devices to the
>   largest, use the .col- classes."

Therefore, to prevent the sidebar from stacking vertically, you'd simply change it from `col-md-2` to `col-2`.

Additionally, the sidebar from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617595/bootstrap-4-holy-grail-layout/42624160#42624160) uses `nav flex-md-column` which makes the sidebar only have a vertical column layout on `md` and larger. The principals are the same as before. To keep the sidebar from switching to a row layout on smaller widths, change it to: `nav flex-column`.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/wVmmn3AwBb

Comment: Thanks. this is working! But can we do sidebar a sticky?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code and it's will work perfectly. If you have

Here is the CSS code: `

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

`

Here is the HTML Codes : `

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap </div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Shortcuts</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
    <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
    <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

`

Here is the JQuery Code :

```
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>
```