# Stretch the item to the entire length of the screen in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How can I stretch the "col" element marked in red to the entire screen length?

[image]

I tried this:

```
class="... w-100"
```

and this:

```
<div class="..." style="height:100vh;">
```

My col element looks like this:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 px-lg-0 border-right-lg border-gray-300 bg-dark text-white w-100" style="height:100vh;">
  [...]
</div>
```

Comment: By *"length"* do you mean `width`? Or both `width` and `height`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 Holy Grail Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617595/bootstrap-4-holy-grail-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your div to have the height equal to the viewport's height, place `vh-100` class on it. Or apply `min-height: 100vh` to it.

If you want it to have full width of the screen, use this markup: `.container-fluid > .row > .col`.

Here's a layout which will always push to the bottom of the screen (as per your picture):

```css
/* test */

.left-col {
  background: indigo;
}
.footer {
  /* this is not needed it if you want content to set its size
   * but mine is empty
   */
  min-height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.full-layout {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.full-layout .row {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.full-layout .row:last-child {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container-fluid full-layout">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 left-col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col vw-100 footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "entire length" you mean "entire height of the viewport":

You probably have two constraints on the minimum hight of the first column:

- at least as long as the view hight
- as long as the longest column in the row

For the first one, `min-height: 100vh` takes care of that, if it's supported by the browser. Just `height: 100vh` doesn't work, because it prevents the second constraint from working.

For the second, since (newer) bootsrap `row`s are flex box, it takes care of that for you.

Alternatively, you could put the minimum height on the row, and that might make more sense, or the container (while also adding a flex column layout).

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  /* If this was a "fixed" hieght, then it wouldn't expand to the whole length of the content (which flex does for you) */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sidebar col">some sidebar content</div>
    <div class="content col">
    Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet tail t-bone meatloaf ribeye chislic chuck meatball pork belly short loin beef shank hamburger ham. <details>Kielbasa alcatra pork belly sirloin, andouille ribeye leberkas ham hock bacon pig tenderloin jerky chicken hamburger meatloaf. Tongue beef ribs shankle fatback swine jerky tail, biltong andouille doner leberkas rump bresaola chicken. Salami bacon frankfurter, brisket ribeye capicola porchetta corned beef strip steak. Turducken burgdoggen salami sirloin, pork kielbasa fatback chislic short ribs porchetta meatball pastrami doner. Ball tip shank jowl tail, short loin shankle chislic. Cow pork loin meatloaf short loin sirloin flank biltong tri-tip filet mignon pork belly brisket rump sausage ground round kevin.

Short loin shankle salami, t-bone andouille buffalo burgdoggen landjaeger swine alcatra sirloin tongue ribeye tenderloin. Shankle ham strip steak, jerky swine bresaola bacon. Tri-tip beef ribs frankfurter, burgdoggen spare ribs picanha porchetta ground round bresaola swine cupim kevin shank. Boudin picanha kielbasa filet mignon beef ribs, sausage prosciutto bacon short loin flank jerky.
     </details>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you meant instead you want a "footer" style element, well, just make another row with only one column. Nothing fancy needed.