# How can I keep Bootstrap columns wide enough for advertisements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I create page with 3 columns with bootstrap5:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">LEFT</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">CENTER</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">RIGHT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in columns left and right there are advertisements with 300px width. How to restrict left and right column to shrink less then 300px, and to shrink just a center column.

If i set min-width:300px on left and right, then right column is pushed down.

Comment: it is pushed down because 300px is wider that 3/12 of your screen size...  why are you using a fixed width with a responsive framework? simply change col-md-3 with col-md-1 or col-md-2 to adapt the size and adapt the center div to fit 12 columns

Comment: Also, please see [ask]. Your snippet (ideally a functional demo) should show what you describe. It doesn't.

Comment: I think you're looking for the "holy grail" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617595

Answer (score 0):

Don't use fixed (proportionate) column sizing. Use [Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/). Here's an example. I've reduced the image size for this demo, but it works the same with 300px images.

You may want to change behavior for mobile, maybe to stack everything so it doesn't wrap oddly. I'm not sure of your goals.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"/></div>
    <div class="flex-fill">CENTER</div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the same (stacked to horizontal) behavior of `.col-md-*`s in a `.row` with flex toggling wrapping at the medium breakpoint with `.flex-wrap.flex-md-nowrap`.
Try this:

```css
.ad {
  width: 300px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap">
    <div class="ad">LEFT</div>
    <div class="w-100">CENTER</div>
    <div class="ad">RIGHT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the Grid [auto-layout columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns). `col-auto` will shrink to fit its content (the ads). Then, use `flex-nowrap` to prevent wrapping...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-md-nowrap">
    <div class="col-md-auto">
        <img src="//via.placeholder.com/300" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">CENTER</div>
    <div class="col-md-auto">
        <img src="//via.placeholder.com/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Responsive Demo](https://codeply.com/p/kd2kBNzFhE)